# how to change the style of a textblock in a button

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, winrt-xaml

I need to change the style of a textblock that it is inside a button..

here are my two styles:

```
        <Style x:Key="btnStyleLR" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Light" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,20,0,20" />
        </Style>

            <Style x:Key="btnStyleLROverride" BasedOn="{StaticResource btnStyleLR}" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,10,0,10" />
        </Style>
```

and then:

```
        <Style x:Key="btnLoginRegister" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="400" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border x:Name="brd"
                                    BorderBrush="Orange"
                                    BorderThickness="1"
                                    CornerRadius="6">

                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           Style="{TemplateBinding Tag}"
                                           Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

I bind the style in the tag property of the button pero it is not works.
then I have two buttons that I need to change de textblock style:

```
                    <Button x:Name="loginBtn"
                        Style="{StaticResource btnLoginRegister}"
                        Tag="btnStyleLROverride"
                        Content="Login" />
```

and the other:

```
            <Button x:Name="registerBtn"
                Content="Register"
                Tag="btnStyleLR"
                Style="{StaticResource btnLoginRegister}" />
```

is there another way to change the style with bind that works? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **`Tag`** you have to **provide resource value, not string**. It should be:

```
<Button x:Name="loginBtn"
        Style="{StaticResource btnLoginRegister}"
        Tag="{StaticResource btnStyleLROverride}"
        Content="Login" />
```

Do it same way for other button.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't destroy a button's template like that, unless it's only for the purpose of this question. The simple solution to your problem is to simply set the `TextBlock` as the button's  content and then you can change its style without hacking through the templates.

Comment: Filip, the template have some visual states that affects the border and textblock's style and it is the only way that I could think.. perhaps it is wrong..

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood your requirements:
You have two `Buttons` ("Login" and "Register") which need to be visually reduced (should not use visual states) and which have their own "text style" each (but maybe sharing a base style)? Is this correct?
If this is the case I recommend two different `Button Styles` (maybe sharing the same base style):

```
<Button x:Name="loginBtn" Content="Login"
        Style="{StaticResource LoginButtonStyle}"/>
<Button x:Name="registerBtn" Content="Register"
        Style="{StaticResource RegisterButtonStyle}"/>
```

And your styles:

```
<Style x:Key="PlainButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Light"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="6">
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="LoginButtonStyle"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource PlainButtonStyle}" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,10,0,10"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="RegisterButtonStyle"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource PlainButtonStyle}" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,20,0,20"/>
</Style>
```

Properties like `FontSize` and `FontFamily` are inherited.